# I cannot execute the function because of the API

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a project and I have a problem with the API.

The problem is that the function is executed before API works. So, the function cannot fetch the API and throws an error.

[image]

I could not figure out how to solve. Thanks in advance! Here is the code:

```
  const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState("")
  const [text, setText] = useState("")
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAnime = async () => {
      const response = await axios(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`, {
        params: {
          limit: 5,
          letter: text,
        },
      })
      // console.log(response.data.data)
      setFetchData(response.data.data)
    }
    fetchAnime()
  }, [text])

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    setText(e.target.value)
  }
  "... Some code"
  "This is where error occurs."
   {fetchData.map((el) => (
          <div className="searchInput" key={el.id}>
            <img src={el.images.jpg.small_image_url} alt="" />
            <p>{el.title}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
```

Comment: Your initial `fetchData` state value is `""`. Because of this, you are trying to map `""` (because on first render, the fetchData value is still an empty string), which is not possible.
Try setting your initial state as `[]`: `const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState([])`.

Comment: you can also use null checks to avoid errors because of the async data operations. For Example: response?.data?.data

it means if the value of the former(before the question mark) variable is null or undefined, it will not go further running the code related to that variable. This is called Optional Chaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that when you render the app, fetchData is a string as your setState.

you can do multiple things to fix this

1. change initial state to an array
2. add an or condition to the map `(fetchData||[]).map`
3. add early return if nothing is set ```!Boolean(fetchData) && return
4. add some loading states that it waits for the promise to fulfilled